# How to SELECT by first characteres and dont get duplicated row? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am bringing data from some courses, which have some sections like "A", "B"... I would like to get only the main course without a section. Image shows the main course at the end and other sections above. Using that course I want to get only `1 / 4 / C-501 / Matematicas Aplicadas I / C-501` .

This is my query. I tried using `DISTINC LEFT(mc.shortname,5)` and `substr(mc.shortname,1,5)` but it doesn´t work. Just cut the section but still bringing all their information.

```
SELECT mc.id, (SELECT mcd.value from mdl_customfield_data mcd WHERE mcd.fieldid =5 AND mc.id = mcd.instanceid)tipo_curso, mcd.value creditos, mc.fullname, mc.shortname
FROM mdl_course mc,mdl_customfield_data mcd
WHERE mc.category = 10
AND mc.id = mcd.instanceid
AND mcd.fieldid = 1;
```

[image: example]

Comment: what do you want if the later parts of the fullname differ (e.g. "C-123A - Foo" and "C-123B - Bar")

Comment: with your sample data, it isn't clear if you just want the id 220 (because that's the one with no A/B/C) or if you want that plus one row for C-502, one row for C-503 etc but with the A/B/C removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the rows where `shortname` always ends in a single letter are the rows you do not want returned.

You can use `REGEXP` to pattern match that in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
   *
from courses
where right(lower(shortname),1) not regexp '[a-z]'
```

Fiddle here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e9b8195b5c93dc1551b25aae6d50578

Comment: unless shortname is binary or has a non-case insensitive collation (either is very unlikely), regexp will be case insensitive.  and it seems like they are always upper case anyway.  so this can just be `where shortname not regexp '[A-Z]$'` (or `a-zA-Z` if it can be lower case and the column is case sensitive)

Comment: Sure, you can do that.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT ON(shortname) * from table ORDER BY shortname;

Comment: 1.) When did MySQL add support for `DISTINCT ON` 2.) Each `shortname` is distinct. I fail to see how this comes anywhere near answering the OP's question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).